# Spring Boot test @Mock annotation doesn't create mock object

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit5

I'm using Spring Boot 2.1 with JUnit 5 and just created a test like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class UserServiceImplTest {

    @Mock
    private AppProperties appProperties;
    @Mock
    private UserAccountService userAccountService;

    @BeforeEach
    void setMockOutput() {
        when(appProperties.getPort()).thenReturn("8088");
        ...
    }


    ...

}
```

The problem is that both variable is null in the `setMockOutput` method even if the `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` annotation is used on the class as mentioned in other SO questions.

If I create the mocks manually like the code below then it works fine:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class UserServiceImplTest {

    private AppProperties appProperties;
    private UserAccountService userAccountService;

    @BeforeEach
    void setMockOutput() {
        appProperties = Mockito.mock(AppProperties.class);
        userAccountService = Mockito.mock(UserAccountService.class);

        when(appProperties.getPort()).thenReturn("8088");
        ...
    }


    ...

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MockitoJUnitRunner is not compatible with JUnit 5.
You need to use `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` instead of it.
This class is located in the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: this test does not start a Spring container

Comment: Unfortunately still the same problem. I don't need the Spring container, the second example is working fine, I just would like to use the annotations instead.

Comment: @Vmxes, are you sure that you are using Mockito version which supports Junit5? It should be `mockito-junit-jupiter` https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-junit-jupiter/3.1.0

Comment: @VadymVL, it seems besides the wrong class annotation my project gradle cache required a refresh. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Using Mockito annotations in JUnit 5 requires you to call MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); before the test method runs. Try adding it to @BeforeEach method and see if it works then. More information about MockitoAnnotations here : https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.28/org/mockito/MockitoAnnotations.html